# Prevent iron-select to be fired when click on element in iron-selector

Tags: javascript, polymer

I'm trying to tap an element inside an `iron-selector` without firing the `iron-select` event.

```
<iron-selector selected="{{selected}}">
   .... lot of content.
   <a on-tap="_save">Save</a>
</iron-selector>
```

I want the `iron-select` event to be fired on all the content, except the `<a></a>`.

I tried to use `preventDefault` but this doesn't works.

I can't move the `<a></a>` out of the `iron-selector`.

Any Ideas?
Help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried `event.stopPropagation();`?

Comment: Ok. I've done that :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [stopPropagation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation). This will prevent the event from bubbling up to the parent element.

```
event.stopPropagation()
```